# LXC: Have rootfs mounted without nosuid

Tags: linux, permissions, setuid, lxc

I have the container's rootfs in a volume mounted with the `nosuid` option. When I start the container, its / mounted is then also mounted `nosuid`, which breaks programs such as `sudo`.

How can I avoid this? I'm not able to remount the the root partition within the container.